# Regex to match lines having specific count of Decimal numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the lines having specific count of decimal numbers separated by spaces. Say lines having only 3 decimal numbers. Consider the below example:

```
 Abc 1.56 1.67 5.67
 xyz 4.51 12.43 32.50
 03/31/2019 $1234 $(1234) $60,501 5.81 7.81
 abcdf $123,345 $123 $123,149
```

For this given input I want to fetch only the first two lines as they have only contains 3 decimal numbers separated by space. I have tried **(.*[\s0-9.]+)$** && **([\s0-9.]+)$** but with these I end up getting many other unwanted lines as well.Could some one please advise if this is something we can do using regular expression.

Comment: Can there be other characters between or after the decimal numbers or do they have to be after each other and nothing following? `^[^\d\r\n]*\d+\.\d+(?: \d+\.\d+){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/DptGHP/1

Comment: No there are no characters in between decimal numbers they are separated by space only. But at starting of lines any characters can be there. Hope that clarifies your doubt.

Comment: The pattern in the previsous comment might work then? Or can there also be digits before?

Comment: or this one: `^[^\\n\\d]*(?>\\d+\\.\\d+ ?){3}$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes there could be digits before as stated starting of line can have any characters. Also if you could elaborate little would be easy for me to understand. As I have just started on regex. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[\s0-9.]+` is a broad match for a decimal number, as it could also match only newlines, spaces or dots.

If there can also digits occur before the decimals, you could use:

```
^.*?\d+\.\d+(?:\h+\d+\.\d+){2}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except an newline non greedy
- `\d+\.\d+` Match a decial number
- `(?:\h+\d+\.\d+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and a decimal number
- `$` End of string

In Java

```
String regex = "^.*?\\d+\\.\\d+(?:\\h+\\d+\\.\\d+){2}$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuCKsx/1)

If the digit before the decimal is optional, you could change it to `\d*\.\d+`

Comment: This is working good for me, just one last query I did not get the 1+ horizontal white space part.

Comment: @GauravParek If you use `\s` you could possibly also match newlines. If there can be spaces only, you could use `[ ]+` But using `\h` will match all horizontal whitespace chars for example also a tab.

Answer (score 0):

To match lines starting with some text, then three decimal numbers separated by spaces, use this regex:

```regex
(?m)^(\p{L}+)\h+(-?[\d.]+)\h+(-?[\d.]+)\h+(-?[\d.]+)\h*$
```

<sup>*Remember to double the `\` when inserting into a Java string literal.*</sup>

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b0m0dg/1) for demo.